# How to user Direct Line to create a real-time messaging in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Is there a way to use direct line from a bot framework to create a real-time messaging application? I need call my Bot directly from a custom MVC application.

The Microsoft Bot Connector Direct Line REST API allows me to do this, but not in real time. Currently I have to make a post action to refresh the screen and get these messages, and it requires a client post action. Do you know a way to achieve this real-time?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take look at the [version 3.0 of the Direct Line API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/), which allows you to use a WebSocket to receive messages.

Comment: I understand your point using the rest api, but this means that I have to use a front end technology as node.js or reactJS to open a channel which will be listening for incoming activities, and I'm trying to avoid this, that's why I was asking about if it is possible open a real-time channel between your controller and view in MVC, always using the Direct Line Client.

Comment: I don't see why you would need nodeJS to use websockets? See [System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I decided use SignalR which inside it uses websocket in this way I can avoid the implementation of all infrastructure that require connections management and object serialization with websockets.